# Moving enums to a different assembly

Tags: c#, .net, enums, .net-assembly

I have an enum type in my first assembly, like below:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   ONE,
   TWO,
   THREE
}
```

Since I wanted to extend my application I have decided to move that to a different assembly (dll) and link it to my first assembly.

When I do that I get a weird result, when I desterilize classes that were serialized when the enum was in the first assembly, they all return first enum member by default.

Is there a solution on how to fix that? 
I even tried to parse it like:

```
(MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), serializer.MyEnumType.ToString());
```

It has no effect.

PS. I use a binary serializer and the enum is in the same namespace and still have the same name.

```
[Serializable]
    public class testClass
    {
        public MyEnum En { set; get; }
    }

    public class test
    {
        void Serialize(string file)
        {
            testClass ser = new testClass();
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            formatter.Serialize(stream, ser);
            stream.Close();
        }
        void DeSerialize(string file)
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            testClass ser = new testClass();
            System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
            ser = (testClass)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737602/cant-deserialize-with-binaryformatter-after-changing-namespace-of-class

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701481/is-it-possible-to-recover-an-object-serialized-via-binaryformatter-after-chang

Comment: Problem is, namespace is the same and so is the class and enum name.

Comment: @Glen if you look close at one of those posts you'll see that the remedy code also changes the _assembly name_ of the object to be deserialized.  I think this is the 'thing' that applies in your case.

Comment: @Glen -- look at the answer which indicates 'you forgot to change the assembly name'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BinaryFormatter` takes into consideration various information about the assembly itself in the serialization process, not just the type's namespace and such. Your problem is occurring because you moved the type to a new assembly so the "serialized" representation is no longer correct.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154046/assembly-independent-serialization-in-net) for an answer to work around this.